# Best way to configure a multiple sets of repositories that connect to different DBs, in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Some of our microservices need to connect to multiple databases. My config classes for repositories end up looking very similar. It's not a lot of code, but it's very boilerplate. 2 to 3 times per microservice and across a lot of microservices it ends up being more repetition than I'd like. Is there a more DRY approach? I'd love a custom annotation that can take a few details and then wire up all the beans I need. But not sure if there's a better solution.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = SomeRepository.class,
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "someEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "someTransactionManager"
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SomeDbConfig {
    @Bean(name = "someDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource(DbProperties dbProperties) {
        ...
    }

    @Bean(name = "someEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("someDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        ...
    }

    @Bean(name = "someTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("someEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing here that auto-configuration won't do for you?

Comment: @chrylis I am not sure. The times I've used auto-configuration I knew in advance that I wanted certain beans created based on some condition. I'm not sure how I could use auto-configuration in this case. How would my auto-configuration code know how many repositories an application wanted?

Comment: *This* code doesn't know "how many" repositories are wanted. You tell `@EnableJpaRepositories` where to look, and it creates the ones that it finds.

Comment: Sorry, I worded my question very poorly. I need to create repositories for different databases. So, an app might have any number of databases that it communicates with. I then have to have similar code to create the repositories for each database.

Comment: Ah, that's a different situation. There might be some help via "Spring repository multiple DataSource", but otherwise, this might be a useful case for something like Spring-Fu.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't even considered Spring-Fu. Most examples I looked at just had multiple config classes.

Comment: I actually am not the biggest fan of Spring-Fu, but this sure looks like a perfect use case.